# How to add a custom image/icon in balsamiq mockups?

Tags: balsamiq

I use balsamiq mockups for creating wireframe screens. I want to add a big calendar to the mockup. so i searched some icons in the balsamiq library and found a "calendar" icon. When i maximized the size of that calendar icon, the clear view of calendar disappeared and it doesn't fit my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using custom icons to design for calendar you can use a grid icon from the tools to make a calendar..

for example , try to drag a "grid" and then draw some lines in it which may look like a calendar. 
Try this. It will fit your requirements.